# "Star Field" Animation with JavaScript and Sass-CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sass

I've have make this animation on the weekend as a "just for fun" thing. And for to play with various techniques I've seen in others code.

I think it works quite alright.

Nevertheless I would appreciate comments about:

1. How to structure / shorten the JavaScript- and Sass-code better?
2. How could the animation be improved? So that it runs smoother and more "natural"?
3. How to improve the responsiveness?

Looking forward to read your comments and suggestions.

```js
'use strict';

var field = document.querySelector('.field');
var starCount = 1000;

function addStar(parent, maxX, maxY) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX + 1));
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY + 1));
  var randomNumber = Math.random();

  var star = document.createElement('div');
  var starTop = document.createElement('div');
  var starBottom = document.createElement('div');
  var styleValue = 'left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px;';
  var starKind = '';

  switch (true) {
    case randomNumber < 0.25:
      starKind = 'large-star';
      break;
    case randomNumber < 0.5:
      starKind = 'medium-star';
      break;
    case randomNumber < 0.75:
      starKind = 'small-star';
      break;
    default:
      starKind = 'tiny-star';
  }

  starTop.classList.add(starKind + '-top');
  starBottom.classList.add(starKind + '-bottom');

  star.appendChild(starTop);
  star.appendChild(starBottom);

  star.setAttribute('style', styleValue);
  star.classList.add('star');
  star.classList.add(starKind);

  parent.appendChild(star);

  return star;
}

for (var i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
  addStar(field, 4000, 400);
}
```

```css
@keyframes rotateStar {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0.09; }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(36deg);
    opacity: 0.18; }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(72deg);
    opacity: 0.27; }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(108deg);
    opacity: 0.36; }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(144deg);
    opacity: 0.45; }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180eg);
    opacity: 0.54; }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(216deg);
    opacity: 0.63; }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(248deg);
    opacity: 0.72; }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(284deg);
    opacity: 0.81; }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(320deg);
    opacity: 0.9; }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(356deg);
    opacity: 1.0; } }
@keyframes moveGlass {
  100% {
    margin-left: -3200px; } }
* {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0; }

body {
  background-color: black; }

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0 20px; }

.field {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
  animation: moveGlass 55s ease-in infinite alternate;
  display: inline-block; }

.star {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotateStar 2s infinite alternate; }

.star .large-star-top:before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .large-star-top:after {
  left: 7px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .large-star-bottom:before {
  top: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .large-star-bottom:after {
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .large-star-top:before, .star .large-star-top:after,
.star .large-star-bottom:before, .star .large-star-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px; }

.star .medium-star-top:before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .medium-star-top:after {
  left: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .medium-star-bottom:before {
  top: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .medium-star-bottom:after {
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .medium-star-top:before, .star .medium-star-top:after,
.star .medium-star-bottom:before, .star .medium-star-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px; }

.star .small-star-top:before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .small-star-top:after {
  left: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .small-star-bottom:before {
  top: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .small-star-bottom:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .small-star-top:before, .star .small-star-top:after,
.star .small-star-bottom:before, .star .small-star-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px; }

.star .tiny-star-top:before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .tiny-star-top:after {
  left: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .tiny-star-bottom:before {
  top: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%; }

.star .tiny-star-bottom:after {
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%; }

.star .tiny-star-top:before, .star .tiny-star-top:after,
.star .tiny-star-bottom:before, .star .tiny-star-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px; }

.star.large-star {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px; }

.star.medium-star {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px; }

.star.small-star {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px; }

.star.tiny-star {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="field"></div>
</div>
```

**Here's the uncompiled Sass-code:**

```
$largeStarDimension: 14px;
$mediumStarDimension: 12px;
$smallStarDimension: 8px;
$tinyStarDimension: 6px;
$animationDuration: 2s;
$windowDimension: 200px;
$primaryColor: #000000;
@mixin addOffsets($starClass, $dimension) {
  .star .#{$starClass}-top:before {
    border-bottom-right-radius:  100%;
  }
  .star .#{$starClass}-top:after {
    left: $dimension;
    border-bottom-left-radius:  100%;
  }
  .star .#{$starClass}-bottom:before {
    top: $dimension;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  }
  .star .#{$starClass}-bottom:after {
    top: $dimension;
    left: $dimension;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  }
  .star .#{$starClass}-top:before, .star .#{$starClass}-top:after, 
  .star .#{$starClass}-bottom:before, .star .#{$starClass}-bottom:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: $dimension + 1;
    height: $dimension + 1;
  }
}
@mixin setStarDimensions($className, $starDimension) {
  .star.#{$className} {
    width: $starDimension;
    height: $starDimension;
  }  
}
@keyframes rotateStar {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0.09;
  }
  10%{
    transform: rotate(36deg);
    opacity: 0.18;
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(72deg);
    opacity: 0.27;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(108deg);
    opacity: 0.36;
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(144deg);
    opacity: 0.45;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180eg);
    opacity: 0.54;
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(216deg);
    opacity: 0.63;
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(248deg);
    opacity: 0.72;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(284deg);
    opacity: 0.81;
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(320deg);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(356deg);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes moveGlass {
  100% {
    margin-left: -3200px;
  }
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.field {
  height: $windowDimension;
  position: relative;
  background-color: $primaryColor;
  animation: moveGlass 55s ease-in infinite alternate;
  display: inline-block;
}
.star {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotateStar 2s infinite alternate;
}
@include addOffsets("large-star", $largeStarDimension / 2);
@include addOffsets("medium-star", $mediumStarDimension / 2);
@include addOffsets("small-star", $smallStarDimension / 2);
@include addOffsets("tiny-star", $tinyStarDimension / 2);
@include setStarDimensions("large-star", $largeStarDimension);
@include setStarDimensions("medium-star", $mediumStarDimension);
@include setStarDimensions("small-star", $smallStarDimension);
@include setStarDimensions("tiny-star", $tinyStarDimension);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to define an animation frame at every 10%. This is prone to many errors (e.g. the change in angle from `60%` to `70%`).

You need only a `from` and a `to` (aliases for `0%` and `100%`):

```
@keyframes rotateStar {
    from { transform: rotate(0); }
    to { transform: rotate(360); }
}
```

I'm guessing you'd like the stars to always rotate in one direction, not alternate in `animation-direction`. One way to do that would be to decouple the star "blinking" and the rotation. Have the opacity be its own keyframe animation. Then you can have the blinking `alternate` while keeping the rotation `normal`.

The rotation animation would work with a `linear` `animation-timing-function`.